# Pod to Pod communication using DNS names

Tags: networking, kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

On my Kubernetes cluster, I have few pods which should talk with each other. They are deployed separately
I've created a headless service called `my-service` which is targeting all the pods.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-service
  namespace: default
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  ports:
  - name: test1
    port: 111
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 111
  - name: test2
    port: 222
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 222
  publishNotReadyAddresses: true
  selector:
    app: "my-app"
  type: ClusterIP
```

Each pod is exposing two ports: 111 and 222

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  labels:
    app: "my-app"
  name: my-service-6c44bdf68c-q6jdq
  namespace: default
spec:
  containers:
  - image: my-image
    name: my-app
    ports:
    - containerPort: 111
      name: test1
      protocol: TCP
    - containerPort: 222
      name: test1
      protocol: TCP
```

When I do `nslookup on my-service.default.svc.cluster.local` I can indeed see all my pods.

I also assign each pod individual hostname and `subdomain: my-service`. Pods now each has a separate DNS A record like: `<hostname>.my-service.default.svc.cluster.local`. So far, so good. But when I try to access pod (from another container) using domain (and port) `<hostname>.my-service.default.svc.cluster.local:111` I got 'Connection refused'. How can I make this work? Am I missing something?

Comment: How are you trying to acess the service from other pod , i mean curl , ping or something else ?

Comment: Ping works. I was trying HTTP connection

Comment: What does nslookup say for the IP of <hostname>.my-service...?

Comment: It gives a correct pod IP

Comment: That means the dns is working fine. Are you sure there's something listening to those ports?

Comment: Your cluster is on cloud or local env? Are you using `kubeadm`, `minikube` or something else? Did you configure your firewall?

Answer (score 0):

The most probable reason for the issue is the way you are trying to reach the service . If you check what responds to port 111 it will work.

For instance making an http connection on a port that doesnot listen to it will give Connection Refused.

Try to ping or telnet as per your service.